# ORACLE TIMEOUTS - how can i set a longer timeout using this connection string?

Tags: oracle

i am using this connection string in .net to connect to oracle and keep timing out getting a large result set.

how can i set a longer connection timeout using this connection string?

```
static private string GetOracleConnectionString()
{
    return "User Id=USER;Password=pass;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=14.12.7.20)(PORT=1139))" +
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=QCTRP1)));";

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
return "User Id=USER;Password=pass;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=14.12.7.20)(PORT=1139))" +
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=QCTRP1)));Connection Timeout=60;";
```

More info on [Oracle Data Provider for .NET / ODP.NET](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p19)

Comment: Is this timeout in milliseconds or seconds? Any documentation on that, i can find/look for?

Comment: Pretty sure connection timeouts are always in seconds as sub-second timeouts don't make much sense. In any case here's a link to some docs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm

Answer (score 5):

are you looking for a [connection timeout](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featConnecting.htm) on the connection string?

> When a connection is closed, the
>   connection pooling service determines
>   whether the connection lifetime has
>   exceeded the value of the Connection
>   Lifetime attribute. If so, the
>   connection is closed; otherwise, the
>   connection goes back to the connection
>   pool.
>   (http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)

or are you looking for the [CommandTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/OracleCommandClass.htm) on the command item?

```
Specifies the number of seconds the command is allowed to execute before terminating the execution with an exception
```

I think for a long running query you will need to extend the CommandTimeout property... however it defaults to 0 (no limit) so you may want to check that